# Basic XSLT transformation with example

Tags: xml, xslt

I have a simple xml:

```
<A>
  <b>
    <c att="1">TEXT <d>some other text</d></c>
  </b>
  <c att="1">TEXT 2</c>
</A>
```

I want to transform it to:

```
<A>
  <p>
    <span class="1">TEXT <d>some other text</d></span>
  </p>
  <span class="1">TEXT 2</span>
</A>
```

How can I do this with a XSLT transformation?

I've tried with this xslt

```
<xsl:template match="b">
    <xsl:element name="p">
      <xsl:copy-of select="node()"/>
    </xsl:element>
  </xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="c">
    <span>
      <xsl:attribute name="class">
        <xsl:value-of select="@att"/>
      </xsl:attribute>
    </span>
  </xsl:template>
```

whith this result

```
<A>
  <p>
    <c att="1">TEXT <d>some other text</d></c>
  </p>
  <span class="1">TEXT 2</span>
</A>
```

Comment: Note that element <A> and <d> must remain the same

Comment: Are you not able to read an XSLT tutorial and post some code you have tried if you get stuck?

Comment: and you are not able to respond without this kind of comment?

Comment: @maurox It's legitimate comment: we are not here to write your code for you. -- As for your attempt, start with the *identity transform* template, and add templates for the nodes you want to modify. And use `xsl:apply-templates` instead of `xsl:copy-of` when you want to modify the copied nodes.

Comment: Ok, i've added a some code and thanks for your replay. I know that you are not here to write code for people. Also i think that for quality your comment is not good too. But ok, thanks for your response!

Comment: @maurox The quality of my comment is not for you to judge. If you don't find it helpful, that's your loss. Good luck finding someone else to help you with that attitude.

Answer (score 0):

As you mentioned, the example is indeed quite basic.

The transformation has to perform the following changes:

1. Change *b* element into *p*.
2. Change *c* element into *span*.
3. Change *att* attribute into *class* (keeping its value).

The 1st task performs template matching *b* element.

The 2nd - template matching *c* element.

The 3rd task performs instruction `<xsl:attribute name="class" select="@att"/>`.

To prevent original `att` attribute from replication in the output,
the embedded `apply-templates` is performed only on descendant nodes covered by
`node()` function, which does not include attributes.

Below you have a complete example.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<xsl:transform xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="2.0">
  <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes" />
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

  <xsl:template match="b">
    <p><xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/></p>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="c">
    <xsl:element name="span">
      <xsl:attribute name="class" select="@att"/>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="node()"/>
    </xsl:element>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy><xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/></xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:transform>
```